# Fetching JSON data on Ajax button click in .net core

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core

I am new to Ajax. Trying to fetch JSON data returned from Get webAPI from controllers but on button click nothing rendering on View.

This is how my view look like

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var ulEmployees = $('#ulEmployees');
            $('#btn').click(function () {
                    var id = $(this).attr(id);
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/api/employee', type: "GET", dataType: "json",
                    data: { id: id },
                    success: function (data) {
                        ulEmployees.empty();
                        $.each(data, function (index, val) {
                            var fullName = val.FirstName + ' ' + val.LastName;
                            ulEmployees.append('<li>' + fullName + '</li>')
                        });
                    }
                });
            });

            $('#btnClear').click(function () {
                ulEmployees.empty();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="btn" type="button" value="Get All Employees" />
    <input id="btnClear" type="button" value="Clear" />
    <ul id="ulEmployees"></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the JSON data returned by webapi[image]

Can anyone help me what went wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is typo near `val.FirstName + ' ' + val.LastName` should be `val.firstName + ' ' + val.lastName;` look closely for upper case and lower case in your json .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below should work:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var ulEmployees = $('#ulEmployees');
    $('#btn').click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        fetch('/api/employee?id=' + id)
        .then((resp) => resp.json())
        .then(function(data) {
        ulEmployees.empty();
            $.each(data, function (index, val) {
                var fullName = val.firstName + ' ' + val.lastName;
                ulEmployees.append('<li>' + fullName + '</li>');
            });
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: Tried this but still not getting the result.

Comment: I am now getting following error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeType' of undefined
    at init.attr (jquery.min.js:5)
    at Function.access (jquery.min.js:4)
    at init.attr (jquery.min.js:5)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (emp:10)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:5)
    at HTMLInputElement.v.handle (jquery.min.js:5)

Comment: this error is near `attr` because `id` should be in quote i.e : `$(this).attr('id')`

Comment: @Swati this solve my error and after making the val.firstName + ' ' + val.lastName i.e. lower casing attribute, I am able to get the result. Thanks a tone. Saved my day :)